# How to quickly determine which number is bigger than the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

$$\{1,2,66,99\}\cup\{5,7,9\}=\{1,2,5,7,9,66,99\}$$

But if I have for example

$$\{0,2,2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{3}\}\cup\{\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},2\sqrt{9}\}$$

Should I first find whose element is bigger than the other and only then I can find the answer?

Comment: Use the fact that $f(x) = x^2$ is crescent for positive numbers. That is: $a_1 > a_2 \Leftrightarrow  a_1^2 > a_2^2$, if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set is just a collection of mathematical objects, it doesn't matter if they aren't well ordered. Imagine you have a bag full of oranges, of different sizes, is it necessary to arrange those oranges by size in order for it to be called a collection of oranges?

And so, you can simply write: $$\{0,2,2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{3}\}\cup\{\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},2\sqrt{9}\}=\{0,2,2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},2\sqrt{9}\}$$ just as you can write it this way: $$\{\sqrt{5},2,2\sqrt{3},2\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7},2\sqrt{9},0\}.$$

Comment: In fact, even writing $\{6,2\sqrt 9\}$ is fine as long as you don't claim that the set has two distinct elements - it is just the same as $\{6\}$.